# Как присвоить значение value в input`e?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 <tr style="display:none;">\
                            <td>\
                                <script>\
                                    $(document).ready(function() {\
                                        var zl="0.07";
                                        var zlz=" zl";\
                                        var tr1=(27090*zl).toFixed();document.getElementById("tr_ergo").value=tr1;document.getElementById("tr1").innerHTML=tr1+zlz;\
                                    });\
                                </script>\
                            </td>\
 </tr>\

var sss = '<tr>\
               <td>\
                  <input type="checkbox" id="tr_ergo" name="tr_ergo" class="switch"/><label for="tr_ergo">Передние эргономичные сиденья</label>\
               </td>\
               <td class = "eq-cost comf_c">\
                  <span id="tr1"></span>\
               </td>\
           </tr>\';
```

Значение Value задал, но я его задал в самой функции $(document).ready(function(), но как их задать вне функции?

Comment: что вы хотите сделать? из вопроса ничего не понятно

Comment: `но я его задал в самой функции $(document).ready(function(),` - не видно по вашему коду чтобы вы там задавали значение чего либо. Кроме переменной `sss`

Comment: Вместо удаления и задания абсолютно такого же вопроса, надо было отредактировать старый вопрос.

Comment: Извините, не знал что так можно. Исправил код, передал в Value значение. Но это я сделал в функции. Как сделать это вне функции?

Answer (score 1):

Понял вопрос по-своему, не серчайте если не то:

```js
//Создаем отдельный файл Javascipt и запихиваем его в head

//Создаем массив в JSON-стиле
var myDetails = [
{name: "шина", price: "3500 руб 1шт", couple: "29500 руб за 10шт", image: "http://shina-lux22.ru/images/tire.png"},
{name: "фара", price: "2500 руб 1шт", couple: "23780 руб за 10шт", image: "http://www.kuzoff.ru/img/TYCAM04-000-L.jpg"},
{name: "стекло", price: "5000 руб 1шт", couple: "47800 руб за 10шт", image: "http://www.glass-cars.ru/images/brend/mitsubishi.jpg"},
{name: "сиденье", price: "10000 руб 1шт", couple: "94620 руб за 10шт", image: "http://www.kolenval.ru/announcement_pictures/0000/5995/00856F_400_3_large.jpg?1241495739"},
];

//Перебираем в цикле
$.each(myDetails, function(){
$("body").append("<div class='detail'>\
<img src="+ this.image +" alt=" + this.name +">\
<span class='holder'>"+ this.name +"</span>\
<span class='price'>"+"Цена:"+ " "+ this.price +"</span>\
<span class='couple'>"+"Оптом:"+ " "+ this.couple +"</span>\
</div>");
});
```

```css
.detail img {width: 130px; height: 120px; display: block;}
.detail span {display: block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Уже ближе, к тому, что вы хотели?

Comment: Не совсем то, у меня есть множество деталей автомобиля допустим. У каждой своя цена. Стоимость их часто меняется. Я хочу их задавать все в одном месте, не шастая по огромному коду. Хочу вынести в отдельное место все. Но если выношу объявление value за функцию, то перестает работать. Может я что-то в видимости переменных не соображаю.

Comment: @pippets Обновил.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Это почти то что нужно)